# How to delete address-object in SonicWALL CLI?

Tags: sonicwall

With the SonicWALL Command Line Interface one can define an address-object.

```
configure
address-object mac cwhii-test
address 11:22:33:44:55:66
zone OK_TEST
```

How does one delete an address-object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
configure
no address-object mac cwhii-test
```